# Using CSP rules per Page

Tags: wicket, content-security-policy

Following the description in https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_content_security_policy_csp all CSP rules are managed via Application settings (class `ContentSecurityPolicySettings`). This means it is not possible to add additional rules on the fly dynamically to the Content Security Settings class. For example, if a specific page within the Wicket application wants to add its own specific URL to the whitelist, this has to be done during the initializing phase of the application.
Is there a way to contribute or to add rules to the list of CSP directives (class `CSPHeaderConfiguration`) per component or page?
What would be the preferred way for doing that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup the CSPHeaderConfiguration and modify it:

```
WebApplication.get().getCspSettings().getConfiguration().get(...).add(key, value)
```

The settings are evaluated dynamically, so you can add/remove at any time.

Comment: Great! I didn't noticed that. This means that each Component (or even Behavior) could add it's own rules/directive to the CSP configuration. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to add additional CSP directives/values in the onInitialize method of a Panel. I'm not sure whether this is the preferred way. The added values are considered only with the next request cycle (page reload). Another problem is, the added values are still in the configuration even if leave the page. This is actually not feasable. There shoudl be some kind of sophisticated mechanism where each Component/Behavior could add and remove CSP rules dynamically and only if needed.

Comment: CSP directives are used as response headers. I.e. you make a request to PageA, it renders itself with some CSP headers in the response. I have the feeling you are not sure how exactly CSP works.

Comment: Yes, each component could add additional rules/directives but you can't remove them. You can only remove the whole CSPDirective but not a special value you have added. So, for example, if you add a fixed CSP value like "www.foo.com" for a component you can not remove exactly this value without removing all values for the directive used.
Or do I miss something? My opinion is, that each component should provide its own rules and only if the component is visible and used on a page, these directives should be rendered in the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation it is not clear since which Wicket version you can use this, but you can use [`ContentSecurityPolicySettings.setProtectedFilter(...)`](https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/apidocs/9.x/org/apache/wicket/csp/ContentSecurityPolicySettings.html#setProtectedFilter(java.util.function.Predicate)) to exclude pages from having the global CSP set.

Modify `init()` of your Wicket web application class:

```java
@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();

    getCspSettings().setProtectedFilter(requestHandler ->
            requestHandler instanceof RenderPageRequestHandler
                    && !PageWithOwnContentSecurityPolicy.class.equals(
                    ((RenderPageRequestHandler) requestHandler).getPageClass()));
}
```

You can then add the `Content-Security-Policy` header by overriding [`WebPage.setHeaders(...)`](https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/apidocs/9.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html#setHeaders(org.apache.wicket.request.http.WebResponse)) in your page class.